# Multiple directories in Makefile target path, $@ only contains top directory

Tags: makefile

I have this target in my Makefile, BUILD and SOURCE are directory paths.

```
$(BUILD)/%.o: $(SOURCE)/%.c
    @echo "In target: "'(BUILD)/%.o: (SOURCE)/%.c'
    @echo "(BUILD) = $(BUILD)"
    @echo "      @ = $@"
    @echo "   (@D) = $(@D)"
    @echo "   (@F) = $(@F)"
    gcc -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

I added these echo commands to make it clear where my confusion is - now here's the output when I try to run this:

```
In target: (BUILD)/%.o: (SOURCE)/%.c
(BUILD) = build/debug
      @ = build/main.o
   (@D) = build
   (@F) = main.o
gcc -o build/main.o source/main.c -c -Iinclude -g
```

So, why aren't `$@`, `$(@D)`, or `$(@F)` acting as I would expect them to? Shouldn't `$@` be `build/debug/main.o` since that's the actual target?

Comment: That is strange.Can you give us a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), enough of the makefile to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 1):

There is only one possible way this can happen, assuming the example above is accurate.

When you defined the rule, the value of the `BUILD` variable must have been `build`.  Then sometime after the rule was defined, you changed the value of the `BUILD` variable to `build/debug`.  Maybe you did this directly, or maybe you did it through a target-specific variable.  But that's the only way you can get the results you've shown us given that rule.

Comment: You are correct. Normally I want to use `build` however if I run `make debug` I want it to use `build/debug` (that way it doesn't see the object files compiled without `-g` and assumes the target is up to date).

Comment: Well, you can't do that (at least not like that).  The manual is pretty clear about this: _As with automatic variables, [target-specific] values are only available within the context of a target’s recipe (and in other target-specific assignments)._  This means you cannot use these values when defining targets or prerequisites.  This would require a catch-22: you can't know which target-specific variables to apply until you define the target, but you can't define the target until you know what variables to apply...